# Proof for a classifying space for $K$ Theory.

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, homotopy-theory, operator-algebras, topological-k-theory

The goal of my question is to understand a bijection between $K_0(A)$ to $[C_0(\Bbb R), M_2(M_\infty(A))]_*$

---

$$[C_0(\Bbb R), M_2(M_\infty(A))]_*$$
is the homotopy class of graded $*$-homomorphisms. $C_0(\Bbb R)$ is graded by even and odd functions. $M_2(M_\infty(A))$ by diagonal (even) and off diagonal elements (odd). This extends uniquely to a graded $*$-homomorphism of their unitzation, 
$$[C(\Bbb R)_+, M_2(M_\infty(A)_+)]$$
where we may regarde $C_0(\Bbb R)_+ $ as $C(S^1)$ by the Cayley trasform $x \mapsto (x+i)(x-i)^{-1}$. The grading on $C(S^1)$ to make everything is given by $f(z)\mapsto f(\bar{z})$ as explained by s.harp.

---

A $*$-homomoprhism is determined by the image $j:S^1 \hookrightarrow \Bbb C$. Denote this image by $u$. As shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3188590/what-cayley-transformation-does-to-a-homomorphism) post.
$$\alpha(u)=u^* \quad (I) $$

Note that there is also a grading on $\varepsilon \in M_2(M_\infty(A)_+)$ by 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
and that $\alpha(x)=\varepsilon x \varepsilon$ for all $x$.

---

There isa bijection between all elements $u$ that satisfy (I) and the projections, given by 
$$ u \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(1+u\varepsilon)$$

---

**MAP I :** $ \Phi: K_0(A) \rightarrow [C_0(\Bbb R), M_2(M_\infty(A))_+]$.

Let $[p]-[q] \in K_0(A)$, then we send 
$$f \mapsto 
\begin{pmatrix}
pf(0) & 0 \\ 
0 & qf(0) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

**MAP II:** $ \Psi: [C(S^1), M_2(M_\infty(A))_+] \rightarrow K_0(A)$.

Given a unitary $u \in M_2(M_\infty(A))_+$  satisfying $(I)$ assign it the element

$$[p_1] - [p_\phi] \in K_0(A)$$

---

> I would like to understand how the maps defined are bijections. I am more concerned with the direction with how showing $\Phi \circ \Psi$ is the identity.

---

This is a translation of [Proposition 3.17, pg43](http://folk.uio.no/rognes/higson/Book.pdf) of Higson's notes. The post should be self contained.